# Bash script Find difference between two strings

Tags: bash

Given these two strings:

```
"12345"
"1245"
```

Where the first one is the complete string and the second has things missing from the first, I want it to return "3".

So again with:

```
"The ball is red"
"The is red"
```

I want to to return "ball"

I've tried diff with:

```
diff <(echo "12345") <(echo "1245")
```

But diff isn't giving the desired output. comm doesn't do what I want either.

Answer (score 5):

I think that `comm` is the correct command:

```
comm -23 <(tr ' ' $'\n' <<< 'The ball is red') <(tr ' ' $'\n' <<< 'The is red')
```

or more flexible:

```
split_spaces() { tr ' ' $'\n' <<< "$1"; }
split_chars() { sed $'s/./&\\\n/g' <<< "$1"; }
comm -23 <(split_spaces 'The ball is red') <(split_spaces 'The is red')
comm -23 <(split_chars 12345) <(split_chars 1245)
```

Comment: Sort is needed in general case. As in `comm -23 <(tr ' ' $'\n' <<< $a | sort) <(tr ' ' $'\n' <<< $b | sort)`

Comment: Apart from @SidaZhou's addition, it may needs -13 instead of -23 if the sentences were in the opposite order for example. `comm --help` describes it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Using only one external executable:

```
a='The ball is red'
b='The is red'
join -v 1 <(echo "${a// /$'\n'}") <(echo "${b// /$'\n'}")
```

Using `join` and `grep` on strings with no spaces:

```
a=12345
b=1245
join -v 1 <(echo "$a" | grep -o .) <(echo "$b" | grep -o .)
```