# Print differences between not sorted strings from files

Tags: bash, comm

I have two files that contain n lines with a string in each line. I want to print out the difference in characters between those lists. You could imagine the operation as a sort of "Subtraction" of letters. This is how it should look like:

```
List1       List2      Result
AaBbCcDd    AaCcDd     Bb
AaBbCcE     AaBbCc     E
AaBbCcF     AaCcF      Bb
```

Which means that the second list is not sorted alphabetically, but all the substrings to remove are sorted within each string (`Aa` comes before `Bb` comes before `Cc`). Note that the elements to remove can be either 1 or 2 characters long (`Aa` or `F`), always starting with uppercase letters followed (sometimes) by a lowercased letter. The strings are completely composed of permutations of a few "elements" like `Aa`, `Bb`, `Cc`, `Dd`, `E`, `F`, `Gg`, ... and so on.

This question has been answered in very similar form here:
[Bash script Find difference between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223890/bash-script-find-difference-between-two-strings),
but only for two strings entered manually, whereas I need to do the operation many hundreds of times. I am struggling with implementing files as a source to this command while also separating the characters correctly. Here is my adaptation:

```
split_chars() { sed $'s/./&\\\n/g' <<< "$1"; }
comm -23 <(split_chars AaBbCcDd) <(split_chars AaCcDd)
```

which gives as output

```
B
b
```

so still not quite what I want even in this single case. I guess that the `split_chars` command is the key here but I was not able to apply it to my files in any way. Putting the file names inside the brackets does not work obviously. 
For reference, a simple

```
commm -23 List1 List2
```

just leads to

```
AaBbCcDd
AaBbCcEe
AaBbCcF
comm: file 2 is not in sorted order
```

Comment: Well they aren't. The strings are composed of permutations a few elements like ``Aa``, ``Bb``, ``Cc``, ``Dd``, ``E``, ``F``, ``Gg``, ... and so on.

Comment: Only the order of strings in the second list is not sorted, but the elements within each string is sorted alphabetically, so ``AaBb`` exists while ``BbAa`` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to split characters but substrings starting with an uppercase letter you should replace `split_chars` with the following function.

```
split() { sed 's/[A-Z]/\n&/g' <<< "$1"; }
```

Splitting a line can be undone by deleting all newline characters using `tr -d \\n`.

To subtract a list of lines from another list of lines you can use `grep` without having to sort.

```
grep -vFxf subtrahend minuend
```

This will print in original order those lines from file `minuend` which are not in file `subtrahend`.

To put everything together, you have to

- read both files line by line in parallel
- split each string into a list of lines
- subtract those lists
- undo the splitting

Here is a simplified version assuming your input files contain only lines of the described format and have the same length.

```
split() { sed 's/[A-Z]/\n&/g' <<< "$1"; }
subtract() { grep -vFxf "$2" "$1"; }
union() { tr -d \\n; echo; }
paste List1 List2 | while read -r minuend subtrahend; do
    subtract <(split "$minuend") <(split "$subtrahend") | union
done
```

Bash scripts with loops are slow. If you need a faster solution you should rewrite this script in a more advanced language like `perl` or `python`.

Answer (score 0):

Another in GNU awk:

```
$ gawk 'NR==FNR {
    a[FNR]=$0
    next
}
{
    patsplit($0 a[FNR],b,/[A-Z][a-z]?/)
    printf "%s%s%s", a[FNR],OFS,$0
    for(i in b)
        if(!(match($0,b[i])&&match(a[FNR],b[i])))
            printf "%s%s", OFS, b[i]
    print ""
}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
List1 List2
AaBbCcDd AaCcDd Bb
AaBbCcE AaBbCc E
AaBbCcF AaCcF Bb
```