# Bash: Append text in-line with ^M-polluted strings

Tags: sed, carriage-return

The focus of this question shifted a bit, the real problem is addressed in Edit 2 below. The problem at the start:

I want to append a simple string, for example the letter `N`, to all lines in my file. This must happen without introducing linebreaks. What I need looks like this:

```
file     result
Aa       AaN
Bb       BbN
C        CN
Dd       DdN
```

The only thing I found so far is

```
sed -e 's/../&N/'
```

which appends the string only at a certain location, so for entries with varying character length this does not work as the result looks like this:

```
AaN
BbN
C
N
DdN
```

The most simple analogon is

```
sed -e 's/^/&N/' file
```

which **prepends** each line. So I need the reverse parameter of `^` that allows me to append to each line, no matter how long the string is in that line. The other questions I found about appending introduce several other constraints that don't apply here.

---

Edit:
The suggested

```
sed 's/$/N/' file > file2
```

only changes the very *last line* in my file., whereas I need the change in every line. It seems to work in the linked question but here it does not. I don't know why.

---

Edit 2:

As RavinderSingh13 pointed out, my list that I obtained by some other commands contained `^M` characters. So by using

```
cat -v file
```

the real content was revealed:

```
Aa^M
Bb^M
C^M
Dd^M
```

The presented solution was able to fix this issue!

Comment: `sed 's/$/N/' file  > newfile`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add text at the end of each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978504/add-text-at-the-end-of-each-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ok with `awk`, you could simply use print instead of substitution too.

```
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"");print $0"N"}'  Input_file
```

In case you want to do for a specific field vice then try:(taking example where 1st field should be append with `N` here):

```
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"");$1=$1"N"} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: Your first piece of code outputs only the very last line and even in the wrong fashion: ``Nd``. The second example looks correct, but again touches only the last line.

Comment: @And, could you please check if you have control M characters in your Input_file by doing `cat -v Input_file` and let us know.

Comment: it seems I do. Every element is listed with ``^M`` in between. I guess that changes the picture.

Comment: @And, I knew it, I updated my answers kindly check them and let me know then? I think you don't need `\r` so I have added logic to remove them from lines.

Comment: It changed now, but the output is stil not quite correct. Instead I get ``AaBbCDdN``. However when I write a new list in a fresh file the result is correct. Sadly my input file is generated by a special command and too long to write by hand, you can see here for details on how I obtained it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55726452/print-differences-between-not-sorted-strings-from-files, Maybe this helps overcome the problem.

Comment: @And, `\r` wouldn't come by commands it comes when a file is copied from windows to unix system, so either you could use `dos2unix` utility(after generating file run it to remove junk characters) OR use like `tr -d '\r < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file` and let me know then?

Comment: Okay, now I was able to do it. I freshly generated the list again and used your first line of code on it. It still contained ``^M`` characters as ``cat -v`` shows, but a linebreak after each as well. Now I have the desired output. Thank you for helping me pick up my mess! Do you have a suggestion on how to edit my post to make it useful to others?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

```
sed 's/\r*$/N/'
```

Look:

```
$ cat -v file
Aa^M
Bb^M
C^M
Dd^M

$ sed 's/\r*$/N/' file | cat -v
AaN
BbN
CN
DdN
```

Comment: Very nice, this is even simpler. Since RavinderSingh13 helped me unravel my problem I leave his answer as accepted, else I would accept this answer now.

Answer (score 0):

without `-i` option to get file changed, tried on gnu sed:

```
sed -E 's/$/N/' file
```

Comment: This changes the very first letter to ``N`` as well.