# Bourne Shell compare two strings

Tags: string, scripting, comparison, sh

I need to compare two string in Bourne shell of the same fixed length. I need to compare each character against the place holder in the opposite string and find out how many differences there are. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about this?

I am just after a way of the number of differences i.e. if I compared aab & aac the differences would be 1.

This also has to be 100% bourne.

Comment: You have to do this in Bourne and not Bash? What kind of antiquated system is this?

Comment: @Mark Thomas: What kind of programmer would use bashisms when a bourne solution does the trick? Who is *still* using bash when there's zsh? See, it's all a matter of preference and what you're used to or what your OS comes with.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to accomplish what you seek (that I know of), but the following snippet of code should get you started:

```
STRING1="test"
STRING2="te5t"

COUNT=0
while [[ $COUNT -lt ${#STRING1}  ]]
do
    POS=$(($COUNT + 1))
    char1=$(echo "${STRING1}" | cut -c $POS)
    char2=$(echo "${STRING2}" | cut -c $POS)
    if [ $char1 != $char2 ]; then
        echo $char1
        echo $char2
    fi

    COUNT=$(($COUNT + 1))
done
```

Comment: Know anyway of pulling each char out in Bourne shell sorry can not have any bash.

Comment: I have updated the code sample above. I only have Bash available to me at the moment, but the code passes Bash's Bourne shell compatibility.

Comment: The double square brackets aren't available in Bourne shell.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind creating temporary files, you can use the cmp method. With the Bourne shell you are pretty limited with what you can do. I would either use zsh/bash or if sh was essential, write a C program that did what I want.

If creating files every time is out of the question, you could create fifos, but this is really hackish and ugly, don't do it!

```
mkfifo cmp1
mkfifo cmp2
echo "abcd" > cmp1 &
echo "abce" > cmp2 &
DIFF_CHARS=`cmp -l cmp1 cmp2 | wc -l`
```

Process substitution in Bash or any modern shell makes this trivial and I would definitely try to use that.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty pure POSIX shell. It runs in Dash (as `sh`) and BusyBox Ash (as `sh`) and uses no external utilities (unless your shell doesn't have a builtin `printf`):

```
#!/bin/sh
string1="compare"
string2="c0mp4r3"

count=0
while [ -n "$string1" ]
do
    char1=$(printf "%1.1s" "$string1")
    char2=$(printf "%1.1s" "$string2")
    if [ "$char1" != "$char2" ]
    then
        count=$(($count + 1))
    fi
    string1=${string1#$char1}
    string2=${string2#$char2}
done
echo "There are $count differences"
```

This will run on the OBG<sup>1</sup>, the [Heirloom Bourne Shell](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html):

```
#!/usr/local/heirloom-bin/sh
string1="compare"
string2="c0mp4r3"

count=0
while [ -n "$string1" ]
do
    char1=`printf "%1.1s" "$string1"`
    char2=`printf "%1.1s" "$string2"`
    if [ "$char1" != "$char2" ]
    then
        count=`expr $count + 1`
    fi
    string1=`echo "$string1" | cut -c 2-`
    string2=`echo "$string2" | cut -c 2-`
done
echo "There are $count differences"
```

<sup>1</sup> *Oldie But Goody* or *Original Bourne Granddaddy*

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{gsub(/[^[:alnum:]_[:blank:]]/, "", $0);for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {freq[$i]++}} END {for (word in freq){printf "%d\t%s\n", freq[word],word}}' {file} | sort -nr
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably answer  you want ... [Bash string difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454427/bash-string-difference/454579#454579)

Using `cmp` to compare the two strings (`diff` won't give you the detail level you want.)

Answer (score 0):

For educational purposes, here's a pure Bourne (and POSIX) solution, without extra forks. POSIX shells can run this even without any forks at all with `COUNT=$((COUNT+1))`:

```
#!/bin/sh

a=$1 b=$2

COUNT=0
while [ -n "$a" ]; do
  [ "${a%${a#?}}" != "${b%${b#?}}" ] && COUNT=`expr $COUNT + 1`
  a=${a#?} b=${b#?}
done
echo COUNT=$COUNT
```

Lets run this on the OP's strings:

```
$ ./x.sh aab aac
COUNT=1
```