# Highlight String Differences

Tags: bash, shell, colors, diff

I am looking for a way to highlight the differences between 2 strings. The idea is to show, in a terminal, what characters were changed by iconv. Both strings are already processed to remove leading and trailing spaces, but internal spaces must be handled.

```
RED="$(tput setaf 1)"    ##    Short variables for the tput ->
CYA="$(tput setaf 6)"    ## -> commands to make output strings ->
CLS="$(tput sgr0)"       ## -> easier to read
str1="[String nâmè™]"    # String prior to iconv
str2="[String name[tm]]" # String after iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit
```

Ultimately I want to automate the formatting of the differences so they are surrounded by tput color codes that I can echo to the terminal.

`${str1}` = Highlight in red, characters not common to both strings

`${str2}` = Highlight in cyan, characters not common to both strings

Wanted Output:

```
output1="[String n${RED}â${CLS}m${RED}è™${CLS}]"
output2="[String n${CYA}a${CLS}m${CYA}e[tm]${CLS}]"
```

Most diff utilities I looked at work on the line or word level. I was thinking of parsing the output of cmp for the byte# of the first diff, but I would have to re-parse for multiple differences it seems.

Anyway I think about it, it seems like it going to be an involved process so I just want to make sure I'm not missing an obvious solution or tool.

Right now I'm thinking the easiest way would be to format each string to put a single byte on a new line and then my options open up.

```
nstr1="$(fold -w1 <<< "$(echo "${str1}")")"
nstr2="$(fold -w1 <<< "$(echo "${str2}")")"
diff <(echo -e "${nstr1}") <(echo -e "${nstr2}")
```

This is as far as i got and didn't want to go further unless I was on the right track. I'm certain there is a zillion ways to do this but is there a more efficient way to go here?

Comment: My ultimate goal is stated in the "Wanted Output", but I think I get your meaning. I thought it relevant to show how I wanted to use the difference output as it might affect how to get there. I'm guessing the question is too broad. I'll remove the question if you think it best.

Comment: The approach is clear enough - a bit of a nuisance to parse the output of `diff` and construct the outputs, but still better than reinventing `diff`.

Comment: Hopefully I made the question a bit clearer. @Thomas, it seemed like a "nuisance" to me as well which is why I thought I might be overlooking something.

Comment: Agreed - I don't recall anyone doing exactly this parser, though it reminds me of things that I've done [here](http://invisible-island.net/personal/oldprogs.html#y1983) and [here](http://invisible-island.net/diffstat/diffstat.html).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Dickey. That actually answers my question. I just didn't want to dive in head first if there was a vastly simpler way. I't's certainly not critical for my script, but seemed like a good project to learn from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it all together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Using stdin input, outputs each char. on its own line, with actual newlines
# in the input represented as literal '\n'.
toSingleCharLines() {
  sed 's/\(.\)/\1\'$'\n''/g; s/\n$/\'$'\n''\\n/'
}

# Using stdin input, reassembles a string split into 1-character-per-line output
# by toSingleCharLines().
fromSingleCharLines() {
  awk '$0=="\\n" { printf "\n"; next} { printf "%s", $0 }'
}

# Prints a colored string read from stdin by interpreting embedded color references
# such as '${RED}'.
printColored() {
  local str=$(</dev/stdin)
  local RED="$(tput setaf 1)" CYA="$(tput setaf 6)" RST="$(tput sgr0)"
  str=${str//'${RED}'/${RED}}
  str=${str//'${CYA}'/${CYA}}
  str=${str//'${RST}'/${RST}}
  printf '%s\n' "$str"
}

# The non-ASCII input string.
strOrg='[String nâmè™]'

# Create its ASCII-chars.-only transliteration.
strTransLit=$(iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit <<<"$strOrg")

# Print the ORIGINAL string with the characters that NEED transliteration
# highlighted in RED.
diff --changed-group-format='${RED}%=${RST}' \
  <(toSingleCharLines <<<"$strOrg") <(toSingleCharLines <<<"$strTransLit") |
    fromSingleCharLines | printColored

# Print the TRANSLITERATED string with the characters that RESULT FROM
# transliteration highlighted in CYAN.
diff --changed-group-format='${CYA}%=${RST}' \
  <(toSingleCharLines <<<"$strTransLit") <(toSingleCharLines <<<"$strOrg") |
    fromSingleCharLines | printColored
```

This yields:

[image: output]

Comment: I almost finished putting this together but you beat me to it and glad you did. I like the `sed` solution and will use it in my code.

Comment: Good work! On macOS the built-in _"Terminal"_ app when set to emulate `vt100` this results is no printed color output. However declaring the _"Terminal"_  as `ansi` or `xterm-color` results in the desired color output (i.e. change it in the _"Advanced"_ settings tab). Is there any way to get this to also work successfully when set to `vt100`, perhaps by changing value of `tput setaf` ?

Comment: Thanks, RobC, but from what I can tell `xterm-256color` is the default (try as the Guest user, for instance), which does support colors; I'm not familiar with `vt100`.

Comment: Yes agreed, you're correct I just restored defaults (I must have tinkered previously). I'm not fully sure on the differences, (if any at all), I've always used the term [ANSI/VT100](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) interchangeably regarding color/formatting codes - so was a bit surprised when _"Terminal"_ app is set to `vt100` there was no colored output. I guess this is less of concern for me now I know the default setting on macOS (it's also fine with iTerm).

Answer (score 2):

Answer provided by @Thomas Dickey in comments that there was no tool or process that was vastly easier than the way I was attempting it.

Just to finish up, I was able to produce the "**Wanted Output**" simple enough with the following `diff`lines.

```
diff --changed-group-format="\${RED}%=\${CLS}" <(echo -e "${nstr1}") <(echo -e "${nstr2}")|tr -d '\n'
diff --changed-group-format="\${CYA}%>\${CLS}" <(echo -e "${nstr1}") <(echo -e "${nstr2}")|tr -d '\n'
```

Unfortunately I haven't figured out how to echo the output to interpret the color codes, but that's another question.

Comment: Interesting, but how does that generate _character_-level differences? How do `nstr1` and `nstr2` relate to `str1` and `str2` from your question?

Comment: @mklement0: If I understand what you are asking, I couldn't use `diff` on `str1` & `str2` to find what characters to highlight as `diff` works on the line level. So `nstr1` & `nstr2` are identical to `str1` & `str2` but with a single character on each line so `diff` will work at the character level.

Comment: Ah, I see; I'd forgotten about your `fold -w1` command to create the each-character-on-its-own line representation. +1 for the approach. Perhaps you can amend your answer to show a self-contained working example. Also, your second command mistakenly contains `nstr1` _twice_. In case you aren't already aware: you can accept your own answer after 48 hours.

Comment: I've posted a solution that puts it all together. Note that I'm using `sed` rather than `fold` to split the strings into indiv. characters, because _GNU_ `fold` is not Unicode-aware, and splits into _bytes_ rather than characters.