# Is it possible to 'git diff' 2 strings?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I have 2 strings and I want the git diff between them. I could create file1 and add string1 as its contents.

Then I could create file2 and add string2 as its contents. Then I could git diff file1 and file2.

However, given that I have the strings as strings (and not as file contents) can I avoid these long-winded steps? Is there an easier way?

Something like:

```
git diff "my first string" "my second string" # obviously does not work
```

Comment: Why would you want to use git for this? Are the string single or multi line?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you insist on the git way,

```
git diff $(echo "my first string" | git hash-object -w --stdin) $(echo "my second string" | git hash-object -w --stdin)  --word-diff
```

Comment: how would i handle new line chars? I tried \n but no joy - thanks - needs to work for windows and linux

Comment: @danday74 Plus `-e` after `echo`.

Comment: does not seem to work anymore: git version 2.30.2

Comment: @BookerB Did you run it in a git repository? What was the error like?

Comment: isnt the purpose of string compare to NOT run into git repo folder?error START: fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
warning: Not a git repository. Use --no-index to compare two paths outside a working tree
usage: git diff --no-index [<options>] <path> <path>;error END;
i was using this command for quite some time, until git pushed an update, it worked very well.

Comment: @BookerB This method is equal to writing the two strings into files first and then comparing the two files.  `git hash-object -w` converts the string into a blob object, which  needs a git repository database. Although `git diff --no-index` can compare two files outside a git repository, `git diff --no-index <(echo string1) <(echo string2)` raises an error (at least in Windows git bash). So in order to write and read the git database, this method needs a gitdir, run in a git repository or specifying `GITDIR=/path/to/repo/.git` or `--git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git`.

Comment: Not wokring for me - git version 2.41.0

Comment: @NamGVU What does the error say? I tried with git version 2.41.0 on Windows and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use git diff for that, Git is used to track the changes in your code base.

There is a good linux command for that

```
diff  <(echo "my first string" ) <(echo "my second string")
```

This is a good answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/454549/4620609

Comment: Is there a Windows equivalent to this? I can't seem to get the accepted answer to work.

Comment: Use any diff tool available on Windows... I don't use windows

Comment: git diff is a lot more capable than plain diff.

Answer (score 4):

In the implementation level, I guess,  `git diff` use a certain diff utility (such as diff) to generate patch, and redirect to a pager(default it is `less`) for viewing. So you need not call `git diff` to compare two string.

If you want patch file format as that output by `git diff`, the flowing command will be a help.

`diff  -u <(echo "my first string" ) <(echo "my second string")`

`-u` is appended to tell `diff` to output patch with unified context.

By the way, git provide a configuration item `diff.external` to allow you generate diff not by the internal diff machinery, but using the given command. environment variable `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` has the same effect.