# Unix text diff - no files

Tags: file, unix, compare, diff

I already found a lot of articles with text diff between two files, but nothing to compare only two contents (output of CMD...). I dont want to store the two texts to disc, but I still want to compare them.

Is there anything like that?

```
diff 'aaabbbccc' 'aaaccc'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash string difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454427/bash-string-difference)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Skgland:

```
diff  <(echo "$string1" ) <(echo "$string2")
```