# Diff without files

Tags: diff

Is it possible to use the "diff" tool without having physical files? Something like this:

```
diff "hello" "hell"
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can diff standard input with a file by using the special filename `-`:

```
# diff the contents of the file 'some-file' with the string "foobar"
echo foobar | diff - some-file
```

With bash, you can also use anonymous named pipes (a bit of a misnomer) to diff two pipelines:

```
# diff the string "foo" with the string "baz"
diff <(echo foo) <(echo baz)
```

See also [How can you diff two pipelines with bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345505/how-can-you-diff-two-pipelines-in-bash).