# Is there a PC-based program like Quick Diff?

Tags: diff, utility

Quick Diff is great because - as the author says - rather than "having to create two files ... just paste in fragments of code to perform a diff".  However, it's an online tool, and sometimes I'd prefer not to send code offsite.

Is there a similar, PC-based utility?

Ref: "Quick Diff Online Tool":-  http://www.quickdiff.com/

Comment: Check out this Question on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991722/diff-without-files

Comment: @NiekvanderSteen - thanks I'll remember that one for my Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), it does the exact same thing you say. Plus, it's open source.

If you don't like it, there's also [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), but it requires two files.

Comment: Thanks - that's great. Paste in two code fragments and click Refresh. Hey presto!