# Substituting a command into the parameter list of another command in bash

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, pipeline, expansion

I have a bash script that normally works like this:

```
[...]
file=$1
docommand $x $y $file $z
```

but I'd like to add an option to the script that would tell it to get the data from a command using an [anonymous named pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/345536/411282) instead of the file.  *I.e.,* I'd like to do something approximating

```
file=<(anothercmd arg1 $1 arg3)
```

and have my

```
docommand $x $y $file $z
```

expand to

```
 docommand $x $y <(anothercmd arg1 $1 arg3) $z
```

Is there a way to get the quoting right to accomplish that?

For more concrete context, the script looks at output products from regression tests, normally diffing them from a file with the expected output.  I'd like to optionally pass in a revision and diff to the then-expected result, so `diff $from $to` would expand to `diff <(hg cat -r $fromrev $from) $to`.

Comment: "anonymous named pipe"... isn't that a funny name?

Comment: The correct term is *process substitution*.  What problem do you have with quoting?  The rules on quoting are no different using process substitution to anywhere else.

Comment: I don't think you can do it. The named pipe used for process substitution is temporary, and goes away at the end of the command line where it's used.

Comment: You can just use the process substitution as the first argument to your script, instead of a file name. That is, instead of `myScript fileArg`, use `myScript <(anothercmd arg1 fileArg arg3)`.

Comment: @chepner, I'm aiming to store either the filename or the pipe in a variable, so that the line that executes it is the same in either case.  It looks like Ipor Sircer's answer does this.

Comment: @Barmar, Ipor's answer solves this by delaying the creation of the pipe (by single quoting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use eval:

```
eval docommand $x $y <(anothercmd arg1 $1 arg3) $z
```

example

```
$ f='<(ps)'
$ echo $f
<(ps)
$ cat $f
cat: '<(ps)': No such file or directory
$ eval cat $f
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4468 pts/8    00:00:00 mksh
 4510 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
 4975 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
 4976 pts/8    00:00:00 cat
 4977 pts/8    00:00:00 ps
$
```

Comment: I want to call attention to the single quotes when defining `f` as a process.  This works great for my case, because `eval cat $f` will also work unchanged for the simple file case like `f=~/.bashrc`.

Comment: There may be security considerations to think about if the filename is a commandline argument.