# How to compare content of two commits?

Tags: git, diff, interdiff

Someone `git push --force` and I get merge conflict.

Comparing local and remote branches I can see that (1) last two commits are replaced by (2) only one. And new `242ab72` commit was added.

[image]

Now I want to analyze how commit `5892f6b` differs from `6a53778` commit.

**Is there something similar to next command?**

```
diff -ruBN $(git show 6a53778) $(git show 5892f6b)
```

NOTICE: I do not want to see difference what is changed between `6a53778` and `5892f6b`.
**I want to compare how content of these two commits differ to each other.**

Comment: What is wrong with question? comment please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git 2.19 introduces a new command, `git range-diff` which does this:

> git-range-diff - Compare two commit ranges (e.g. two versions of a branch)

See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52278675/4632019)

example of `git range-diff 94516fd0...a22765c4`

[image]

Comment: Could you replace the picture with text please?  Pictures are not accessible to blind readers.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/345526/4632019):

```
diff -ruBN <(git show 6a53778) <(git show 5892f6b)
```

**UPD**
Also I found [this](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Calling_.22interdiff.22_between_commits):

```
[alias]
        intercommit = !sh -c 'interdiff <(git show $1) <(git show $2) | less -FRS'
```

**NOTICE**
`interdiff` may cause error:

```
interdiff: Error applying patch1 to reconstructed file
```

This occur because `interdiff doesn't have the advantage of being able to look at the files that are to be modified.`