# How to compare local and remote git files?

Tags: git, git-ls-files, git-ls-remote, git-ls-tree

I need to list all <s>tracked</s> commited files that only exist locally. Let's say my local repo is a commit forward the remote repo (on github or gitlab) and these are my local <s>tracked</s> commited files:

```
a.txt
b.txt
```

Now imagine in my remote repo there is just one of those files:

```
a.txt
```

What git command could be used to list the diff between local and remote repos in terms of <s>tracked</s> commited files? To be cristal clear, which git command (git-ls-files, gt-ls-remote, git-ls-tree, etc) could generate the following output:

```
b.txt
```

**EDIT 1**: I have to do this without pulling commits from the remote repo.

**EDIT 2**: I need this to write a git hook to prevent pushes, but I'm not sure this is a good use case for git hooks.

Comment: Note that, aside from getting (or listing with `git ls-remote`) *commits* **from** some other repository, there is no such thing as a "remote repo" in Git: all commits are stored *locally*. You just connect to some other Git (a *remote*) and collect their commits, locally, via `git fetch`, and now you have them ... local! I like to think of Git as The Borg from Star Trek TNG: you introduce it to some other technology, and it just copies it all over.

Comment: This make sense, but I need to compare commits that I didn't pull from a remote repo yet.

Comment: You do not have to run `git pull`. You have to run `git fetch`. That gets the commits into your repository but *does not touch any of your branches*.

Comment: Also worth a side note: a *tracked* file is not a *committed* file. A tracked file is one that is *currently in the index and work-tree*. The index contents change as you select commits, use `git add`, or use `git rm`. Committed files go into the index and work-tree when you `git checkout` that commit, so at that point they're also tracked, but when you're inspecting individual commits, the tracked-ness of a file is irrelevant: all that matters is whether that commit contains that file.

Comment: Yeap, you are right. I will restate the question, removing the term tracked. On the other hand, I think fetching changes doesn't solve my problem since I need to compare actual commits. Maybe I posted the wrong question. I need this because I intend to write a git hook to prevent pushes based on the list of files already commited by other team members.

Comment: I find the updated question less clear: are you asking about *committed* files, or *files in some Git repository's work-tree?*

Comment: I added the term commited. Take a look now. Is is it still confusing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209663/discussion-between-fernando-costa-and-torek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured it out:

```sh
git fetch origin && comm -2 -3 \
  <(sort <(git ls-tree -r master --name-only)) \
  <(sort <(git ls-tree -r origin/master --name-only))
```

Final result:

```
b.txt
```

Thank you *torek* and *polareper*. Your suggestions helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`diff -y <(git ls-files) <(git ls-tree -r master --name-only )`

I am taking the [diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345505/how-can-you-diff-two-pipelines-in-bash) of the files in master to local (`ls-files`).[1](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files)

Comment: At a first glance, I thought your suggestion would solve my problem, but I had to change it a little bit. Thank you.

Comment: Feel free to update my answer